# cant using "LIKE" in native query spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-native-query

I try to get orders of user by query :

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE USER_ID = ?1 AND CAST(CREATE_AT AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE ?2 OR CAST(GRAND_TOTAL AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE ?2 OR CAST(STATUS AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE ?2"  , nativeQuery = true)
Page<Order> getOrdersByUserSearch(int userID, String searchS, Pageable pageable);
```

But it always return empty list. i run this code in SQL server and it work (?1 =2. ?2 = '2021-06-26').
If I try to change "NOT LIKE" instead of "LIKE" It run.
I dont want using query ( not native), Named query or specification method because it get more error.
Any advice?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL `like` query requires `%` along with the value for a match. In case of `ordered parameters` in queries we can use:

```java
    @Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.rating LIKE ?1%")
    List<Movie> searchByRatingStartsWith(String rating);
```

Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-like-queries#2-ordered-parameters) for more info.

In your case the query string should be like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE USER_ID = ?1 AND CAST(CREATE_AT AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2% OR CAST(GRAND_TOTAL AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2% OR CAST(STATUS AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2%
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, my sql is wrong, it should be:     @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE USER_ID = ?1 AND( CAST(ORDER_ID AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2% OR CAST(CREATE_AT AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2% OR CAST(GRAND_TOTAL AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2% OR CAST(STATUS AS NVARCHAR(100))  LIKE %?2%)", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: @THANHTÍNHSHR Glad to know that my answer helped you. Please consider marking it as correct so it can help other people checking this question also! :)